# Get the summary from more than two tables (stock movement report)

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2016

I have a 2 tables,

1- Inward Table

```
CREATE TABLE Inward
(
    GoodsInwardId BIGINT DEFAULT NEXT VALUE FOR SEQ_GoodsInwardId NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    GoodsInwardDate DATE NOT NULL,
    InventoryId BIGINT NOT NULL,
    Quantity DECIMAL(18, 4) NOT NULL
    PRIMARY KEY(GoodsInwardId)
)
```

2- Outward Table

```
CREATE TABLE GoodsOutward
(
    GoodsOutwardId BIGINT DEFAULT NEXT VALUE FOR SEQ_GoodsOutwardId NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    GoodsOutwardDate DATE NOT NULL,
    InventoryId BIGINT NOT NULL,
    Quantity DECIMAL(18, 4) NOT NULL
    PRIMARY KEY(GoodsOutwardId)
)
```

After i filled data in both table Result such as,

[image]

My question is, how can i summarize query such as below screen shot.

[image]

Comment: Please - no screen shots of text/data [ever](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question). Give us DDL and DML that we can run for ourselves!

Comment: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT Date, InventoryID, SUM(InwardQTY), SUM(OutwardQTY)
FROM (
select Date, InventoryID, SUM(QTY) as InwardQTY, NULL as OutwardQTY 
from Inward
group by Date, InventoryID
UNION ALL
select Date, InventoryID, NULL as InwardQTY, SUM(QTY) as OutwardQTY 
from Outward
group by Date, InventoryID
) A
GROUP BY Date, InventoryID
ORDER BY Date, InventoryID
```

Comment: Inward Qty and outward Qty summarized data and inventory Id wise, Pls check my summary screen shot

Comment: Have edited the answer

Answer (score 3):

You can presum the two tables and then FULL OUTER JOIN

```
SELECT isnull(i.Date, o.Date) AS Date, 
    isnull(i.InventoryId, o.InventoryId) AS InventoryId,
    i.Qty InwardQty ,
    o.Qty OutwardQty
FROM
(    SELECT GoodsInwardDate AS Date, InventoryId, SUM(Quantity) AS Qty
    FROM Inward
    GROUP BY Date, InventoryId
) AS i
FULL OUTER JOIN
(    SELECT GoodsOutwardDate AS Date, InventoryId, SUM(Quantity) AS Qty
    FROM GoodsOutward
    GROUP BY Date, InventoryId
) AS o 
ON i.Date=o.Date AND i.InventoryId=o.InventoryId
ORDER BY isnull(i.Date, o.Date)
```

Comment: getting incorrect result!
First coming all the inward table records
after coming  all the outward table records

Please check my summary screen shot in question..

Comment: @M.I.M.F the answer seems correct to me. If you the results ordered in a specific way, add `ORDER BY`. That's irrelevant to the question you asked.

Comment: @M.I.M.F, never copy and use a piece of code that you don't understand. If you figure out what the query does (seems correct to me), it is very easy to adjust it to do what you ask for. As a bonus, you will actually have learned something (which is what StackOverflow etc. is all about)

Comment: @M.I.M.F I added the ORDER BY so you can see them in that order.